# A set of four matrix equations

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Let $\{\mathbf b_1,\mathbf b_2,\mathbf b_3\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ and consider three arbitrary vectors $\mathbf w_i=\sum_j\omega_{ij}\mathbf b_j$.

We define the following two $3\times 9$ matrices
\begin{equation}
B_\Lambda:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf b_1&\mathbf 0&\mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0&\mathbf b_2&\mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0&\mathbf 0&\mathbf b_3
\end{pmatrix}^T,\quad
B_X:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf 0&\mathbf b_3&\mathbf b_2\\
\mathbf b_3&\mathbf 0&\mathbf b_1\\
\mathbf b_2&\mathbf b_1&\mathbf 0
\end{pmatrix}^T
\end{equation}
and define $W_\Lambda$ and $W_X$ in the same way (replacing $\mathbf b_i$ with $\mathbf w_i$ in the above definition).

Consider the following system of matrix equations:
\begin{equation}
B_\Lambda M=O_{3\times3},\quad
B_X M=O_{3\times3},\quad
W_\Lambda M=I_{3\times3}.
\end{equation}
These three equations uniquely determine a $9\times3$ matrix $M$ iff
\begin{equation}
\det\widehat\Omega\neq0\quad \text{where}\quad\widehat\Omega:=
{\small\begin{pmatrix}
0&-\omega_{13}&\omega_{12}\\
\omega_{23}&0&-\omega_{21}\\
-\omega_{32}&\omega_{31}&0
\end{pmatrix}}.
\end{equation}
I would like to know if there is an **elegant** way to compute $W_XM$ under the given conditions.

---

One way to approach the problem is to let $\{\mathbf a_1,\mathbf a_2,\mathbf a_3\}$ be the reciprocal basis to $\{\mathbf b_1,\mathbf b_2,\mathbf b_3\}$, i.e. $\mathbf a_i\cdot\mathbf b_j=\delta_{ij}$, and to express $M$ as
\begin{equation}
M=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf v_{11}&\mathbf v_{12}&\mathbf v_{13}\\
\mathbf v_{21}&\mathbf v_{22}&\mathbf v_{23}\\
\mathbf v_{31}&\mathbf v_{32}&\mathbf v_{33}
\end{pmatrix},\quad \text{where }\mathbf v_{ij}=\sum_k\xi^i_{jk}\mathbf a_k.
\end{equation}
The three matrix equations then descent to equations for the tensor $\xi^i_{jk}$: the first two state that $\xi^i_{jk}$ is antisymmetric in its lower indices, while the third shows that the non-trivial components are
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}\xi^i_{23}\\\xi^i_{31}\\\xi^i_{12}\end{pmatrix}
=\widehat\Omega^{-1}\mathbf e_i,
\end{equation}
where $\{\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Having expressed $M$ in terms of the reciprocal basis, we can express $W_X$ in terms of the original basis through $\mathbf w_i=\sum_j\omega_{ij}\mathbf b_j$, and through tedious matrix multiplication obtain
\begin{equation}
W_XM=
\frac{1}{\det\widehat\Omega}
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_{21}c_{13}-\omega_{31}c_{12}&
\omega_{12}c_{13}-\omega_{31}c_{21}&
\omega_{21}c_{31}-\omega_{13}c_{12}\\
\omega_{32}c_{12}-\omega_{21}c_{23}&
\omega_{32}c_{21}-\omega_{12}c_{23}&
\omega_{23}c_{21}-\omega_{12}c_{32}\\
\omega_{31}c_{32}-\omega_{23}c_{13}&
\omega_{13}c_{23}-\omega_{32}c_{31}&
\omega_{13}c_{32}-\omega_{23}c_{31}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $c_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-cofactor of the matrix $\Omega:=(\omega_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq3}$.

---

While the found expression is certainly quite messy, the amount of regularity suggests that we might be able to rewrite it in a more insightful form. At first the appearance of the cofactors encouraged me to think of something of the form
\begin{equation}
W_XM\overset{?}{=}\frac{\det\Omega}{\det\widehat\Omega}\,\Omega^{-1}\widehat\Omega,
\end{equation}
but this doesn't seem to pan out.